# Docker can not start myproject_mssql-init_1 and myproject_solr-init_1

Tags: docker, container

I'm running up.ps1 in step 7 of Create the MyProject solution in [the Sitecore 10 Getting Started Template](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html). All containers are started except  myproject_mssql-init_1 and myproject_solr-init_1[image]

But up.ps1 continue to run and it can start id.myproject.localhost, cm.myproject.localhost and [www.myproject.localhost](http://www.myproject.localhost).
While id.myproject.localhost and cm.myproject.localhost work for me that myproject.localhost show a exception[image]

I'm not sure the site  [www.myproject.localhost](http://www.myproject.localhost) can not run cause by stopped of myproject_mssql-init_1 and myproject_solr-init_1.

This is console output of up.ps1:

```
Building containers...
mssql uses an image, skipping
solr uses an image, skipping
traefik uses an image, skipping
Building dotnetsdk
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/10 : ARG DOTNET_VERSION
Step 2/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
 ---> 49067b9f938a
Step 3/10 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bdc44ffc2088
Step 4/10 : ENV NUGET_VERSION 5.8.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c8ed4333633c
Step 5/10 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 09ae6a2d1ebe
Step 6/10 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1' -UseBasicParsing -OutFile 'dotnet-install.ps1';
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a34723db865
Step 7/10 : RUN ./dotnet-install.ps1 -Version ${DOTNET_VERSION}             -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet'             -Channel ${DOTNET_VERSION}            -Runtime dotnet;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 159e8be918ad
Step 8/10 : ENV     DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true     DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true     NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 799797e25cad
Step 9/10 : RUN $path = ${Env:PATH} + ';C:\Program Files\dotnet\;';     setx /M PATH $path
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8e3c6f5a6b81
Step 10/10 : RUN dotnet help | out-null
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bee2f0368b2c
Successfully built bee2f0368b2c
Successfully tagged myproject-dotnetsdk:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building solution
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.147MB
Step 1/20 : ARG BUILD_IMAGE
Step 2/20 : FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS nuget-prep
 ---> bee2f0368b2c
Step 3/20 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd6e31fa8a46
Step 4/20 : COPY *.sln nuget.config Directory.Build.targets Packages.props /nuget/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03d8955429d5
Step 5/20 : COPY src/ /temp/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 88249568a542
Step 6/20 : RUN Invoke-Expression 'robocopy C:/temp C:/nuget/src /s /ndl /njh /njs *.csproj *.scproj packages.config'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7afb22f4982c
Step 7/20 : FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS builder
 ---> bee2f0368b2c
Step 8/20 : ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bdd7f9dc6c3e
Step 9/20 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4239cf69e1bf
Step 10/20 : WORKDIR /build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 51b786dcc657
Step 11/20 : COPY --from=nuget-prep ./nuget ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd2e9f43fa4b
Step 12/20 : RUN nuget restore -Verbosity quiet
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c0db12b8259b
Step 13/20 : COPY src/ ./src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65dcbe344eeb
Step 14/20 : RUN msbuild .\src\platform\Platform.csproj /p:Configuration=$env:BUILD_CONFIGURATION /m /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Local
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c6cdcb074ff6
Step 15/20 : WORKDIR /build/src/rendering
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 63cc5e4fd16d
Step 16/20 : RUN dotnet publish -c $env:BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /build/rendering --no-restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c67110bf1e1c
Step 17/20 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
 ---> 90d09aa6b182
Step 18/20 : WORKDIR /artifacts
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f49d00ac0ba
Step 19/20 : COPY --from=builder /build/docker/deploy/platform  ./sitecore/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 58a05fa32795
Step 20/20 : COPY --from=builder /build/rendering ./rendering/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfc28322a2ef
Successfully built dfc28322a2ef
Successfully tagged myproject-solution:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building solr-init
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 3ecd71188776
Successfully built 3ecd71188776
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-solr-init:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building mssql-init
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/5 : ARG HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE
Step 3/5 : FROM ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE} AS headless_services
 ---> c1800b60ff7f
Step 4/5 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> d050ac4bfa39
Step 5/5 : COPY --from=headless_services C:\module\db C:\resources\jss
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f48933bd08e1
Successfully built f48933bd08e1
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-mssql-init:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building id
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/3 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> b3969c34107f
Step 3/3 : COPY readme.md *.xml* .\Config\production\
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a4cc6d619478
Successfully built a4cc6d619478
Successfully tagged myproject-id6:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building xconnect
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> d39fb797c064
Successfully built d39fb797c064
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-xconnect:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building xdbsearchworker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> fa1f3e1d9d78
Successfully built fa1f3e1d9d78
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-xdbsearchworker:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building xdbautomationworker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 9ecae29529c8
Successfully built 9ecae29529c8
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-xdbautomationworker:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building cm
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/19 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/19 : ARG SOLUTION_IMAGE
Step 3/19 : ARG TOOLS_IMAGE
Step 4/19 : ARG MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE
Step 5/19 : ARG HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE
Step 6/19 : FROM ${SOLUTION_IMAGE} as solution
 ---> dfc28322a2ef
Step 7/19 : FROM ${TOOLS_IMAGE} as tools
 ---> 8efbebb2bf67
Step 8/19 : FROM ${MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE} AS management_services
 ---> fcbc8d49a87c
Step 9/19 : FROM ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE} AS headless_services
 ---> c1800b60ff7f
Step 10/19 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 83c5bf00dab6
Step 11/19 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 45890c5b9cab
Step 12/19 : WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f4d4a4a62f5b
Step 13/19 : COPY --from=tools C:\tools C:\tools
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0658057d6de9
Step 14/19 : COPY --from=management_services C:\module\cm\content C:\inetpub\wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f2d3411548d
Step 15/19 : COPY --from=headless_services C:\module\cm\content C:\inetpub\wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c8f5436bd83
Step 16/19 : COPY --from=headless_services C:\module\tools C:\module\tools
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9affe8b2171f
Step 17/19 : RUN C:\module\tools\Initialize-Content.ps1 -TargetPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot;     Remove-Item -Path C:\module -Recurse -Force;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4e806e7b179
Step 18/19 : COPY --from=solution /artifacts/sitecore/ ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8693399852c
Step 19/19 : COPY readme.md *.config*  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Config\Include\
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df7d4234f8b9
Successfully built df7d4234f8b9
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-cm:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building rendering
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/7 : ARG DEBUG_PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/7 : ARG SOLUTION_IMAGE
Step 3/7 : FROM ${DEBUG_PARENT_IMAGE} as debug
 ---> bee2f0368b2c
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /solution/src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d369b6431e2
Step 5/7 : ENV DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_LAUNCH_BROWSER=true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7e141ff00392
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d64f88422a6f
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "-v", "--project", ".\\rendering", "run", "--no-launch-profile"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8488289b1712
Successfully built 8488289b1712
Successfully tagged myproject-rendering:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Building cortexprocessingworker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 133f1363d058
Successfully built 133f1363d058
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Starting Sitecore environment...
Creating network "myproject_default" with the default driver
Creating myproject_solr_1  ... done
Creating myproject_mssql_1 ... done
Creating myproject_mssql-init_1 ... done
Creating myproject_solr-init_1  ... done
Creating myproject_id_1         ... done
Creating myproject_xconnect_1   ... done
Creating myproject_cm_1         ... done
Creating myproject_rendering_1  ... done
Creating myproject_xdbautomationworker_1    ... error
Creating myproject_xdbsearchworker_1     ...
Creating myproject_cortexprocessingworker_1 ...

Creating myproject_xdbsearchworker_1        ... done
Creating myproject_cortexprocessingworker_1 ... done
Creating myproject_traefik_1                ... done

ERROR: for xdbautomationworker  Cannot start service xdbautomationworker: container 33b8ccb8a67b5944f57fc9423eaecb83095d72e2bc367fc645043ed655f5ec6d encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: Element not found. (0x490)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Waiting for CM to become available...
Logging in to Sitecore. You should see a browser window open shortly.
[DeviceLogin] User Code : 299677900
[DeviceLogin] Authentication url : https://id.myproject.localhost/device?userCode=299677900
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
[DeviceLogin] Authorization pending. Waiting.
Your login is complete. You can close the browser tab now.
Login information has been saved.
Populating Solr managed schema...
Populating:
sitecore_core_index [Running]
sitecore_master_index [Running]
sitecore_web_index [Running]
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master [Running]
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web [Running]
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master [Running]
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web [Running]
sitecore_testing_index [Running]
sitecore_suggested_test_index [Running]
sitecore_personalization_index [Running]
sitecore_fxm_master_index [Running]
sitecore_fxm_web_index [Running]
Processing...
The search indexes have been populated:
sitecore_core_index [Completed]
sitecore_master_index [Completed]
sitecore_web_index [Completed]
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master [Completed]
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web [Completed]
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master [Completed]
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web [Completed]
sitecore_testing_index [Completed]
sitecore_suggested_test_index [Completed]
sitecore_personalization_index [Completed]
sitecore_fxm_master_index [Completed]
sitecore_fxm_web_index [Completed]
Pushing latest items to Sitecore...

[master] Discovered 0 changes after evaluating 261 total items.

Opening site...

Use the following command to monitor your Rendering Host:
docker-compose logs -f rendering
```

I also try to start myproject_mssql-init_1 and myproject_solr-init_1 by `docker start ...` but it can not, it show this error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>docker start b204c30a6855f6a42e24a4c0c58b96384d461e1add5a98923d24469c4b711f1d
Error response from daemon: container b204c30a6855f6a42e24a4c0c58b96384d461e1add5a98923d24469c4b711f1d encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)
Error: failed to start containers: b204c30a6855f6a42e24a4c0c58b96384d461e1add5a98923d24469c4b711f1d
```

Do you have any ideas about this issue? Did I do any wrong? Thank for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Docker `init` containers should start, do their job, and exit.
They **should be** in exited mode. That is fine.

However, they should exit with `0` code. `0` means that everything is fine. The container did its job and exited without any issues. It looks like you have an issue only with MSSQL init container.

You need to troubleshoot the problem.

1. Run `docker container ls -a` and find ID of container that exited with code different from 0
2. Run `docker logs [id of the container from step]`. It will give you an understanding of what went wrong.

Comment: Anton, the both is exited 0. myproject_mssql-init_1 just greater than 0 when I try to start. Fom the docker logs I don't see any errors. So we can say myproject_mssql-init_1 and myproject-solr-init-1 are fine.

The remaining problem is that myproject.localhost shows an exception, it show a null exception. Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: Thank for your answer, to focus on the issue, I open a new question and we can close this question. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32500/myproject-localhost-throw-except-because-pagetile-is-null-in-sitecorecontroller

Comment: @NhanNguyen if my answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.