# myproject.localhost throw except because pageTile is null in SitecoreController.cs

Tags: docker

I'm running up.ps1 in step 7 of Create the MyProject solution in the [Sitecore 10 Getting Started Template](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).
While id.myproject.localhost and cm.myproject.localhost work fine for me, but myproject.localhost throw a exception caused by pageTile is null.
[image: pageTile is null]

- This is `docker logs myproject_rendering_1`

```
C:\Users\Admin>docker logs myproject_rendering_1
dotnet watch ⌚ Polling file watcher is enabled
dotnet watch ⌚ Did not find a HotReloadProfile or running a non-default command. Watching with legacy behavior.
dotnet watch ⌚ Evaluating dotnet-watch file set.
dotnet watch ⌚ Running MSBuild target 'GenerateWatchList' on 'C:\solution\src\.\rendering\RenderingHost.csproj'
dotnet watch  Started 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' '' with process id 1280
dotnet watch ⌚ Process id 1280 ran for 1876ms
dotnet watch ⌚ Watching 58 file(s) for changes
dotnet watch ⌚ Watch command can be configured to use --no-restore.
dotnet watch ⌚ No restore arguments: run --no-restore --no-launch-profile
dotnet watch ⌚ Configuring the app to use browser-refresh middleware.
dotnet watch ⌚ Refresh server running at ws://localhost:49176.
dotnet watch  Started 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' '' with process id 1764
dotnet watch ⌚ Running dotnet with the following arguments: run --no-launch-profile
dotnet watch  Started
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {98eeb537-6260-4066-9190-7187ee38a5a1} with creation date 2022-08-05 04:10:05Z, activation date 2022-08-05 04:10:05Z, and expiration date 2022-11-03 04:10:05Z.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
      Writing data to file 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-98eeb537-6260-4066-9190-7187ee38a5a1.xml'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\solution\src\rendering
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.myproject.localhost/ - -
dbug: Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.RequestHandlers.HttpLayoutRequestHandler[0]
      Layout Service Http Request Message : Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://cm/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_apikey={dba6453f-6a71-4de9-b9c3-36ea77fcc730}&sc_site=MyProject&item=%2F&sc_lang=en', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
      {
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
        User-Agent: (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
        User-Agent: AppleWebKit/537.36
        User-Agent: (KHTML, like Gecko)
        User-Agent: Chrome/103.0.0.0
        User-Agent: Safari/537.36
        X-Forwarded-Proto: http
        X-Forwarded-For: ::ffff:172.22.202.43
      }
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.jss-endpoint.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET http://cm/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_apikey={dba6453f-6a71-4de9-b9c3-36ea77fcc730}&sc_site=MyProject&item=%2F&sc_lang=en
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.jss-endpoint.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET http://cm/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_apikey={dba6453f-6a71-4de9-b9c3-36ea77fcc730}&sc_site=MyProject&item=%2F&sc_lang=en
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.jss-endpoint.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2282.6771ms - 403
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.jss-endpoint.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2308.5253ms - 403
dbug: Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.RequestHandlers.HttpLayoutRequestHandler[0]
      Layout Service Http Response : StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Sitecore.LayoutService module requires SXA or JSS license.', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
      {
        Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
        Pragma: no-cache
        Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
        X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
        Set-Cookie: myproject#lang=en; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
        Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gme42feptr4tyesjkmgquic0; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
        Set-Cookie: SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=6ff6735330eb469f815cc6d1545a6f43|False; expires=Mon, 02-Aug-2032 04:22:20 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
        X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
        X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
        Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://apps.sitecore.net; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com; block-all-mixed-content;
        Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2022 04:22:21 GMT
        Expires: -1
        Content-Length: 0
      }
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'MyProject.Controllers.SitecoreController.Index (MyProject)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Sitecore"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index(Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.Response.Model.Field`1[System.String]) on controller MyProject.Controllers.SitecoreController (MyProject).
warn: Sitecore.AspNet.RenderingEngine.Binding.SitecoreLayoutModelBinder[0]

Failed to bind pageTitle to Field`1 type.
Binding Source : RouteField.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyProject.Controllers.SitecoreController.Index (MyProject) in 210.0314ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'MyProject.Controllers.SitecoreController.Index (MyProject)'
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at MyProject.Controllers.SitecoreController.Index(Field`1 pageTitle) in C:\solution\src\rendering\Controllers\SitecoreController.cs:line 11
         at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Sitecore.AspNet.RenderingEngine.Middleware.RenderingEngineMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IViewComponentHelper viewComponentHelper, IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Sitecore.AspNet.ExperienceEditor.ExperienceEditorMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.myproject.localhost/ - - - 500 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 3518.4161ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.myproject.localhost/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.myproject.localhost/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js - - - 200 11944 application/javascript;+charset=utf-8 3.1165ms
```

Do you know what problems? How can I solve it?

Comment: did you publish the website?

Comment: Not yet, this is first time I run up.ps1 to start application, I follow this document at step 7. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Comment: Please try publishing your website

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the website for seeing your changes on the cd instance. If you will see the **Test the MyProject solution** section on the same URL - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html#test-the-myproject-solution it is pointing to publish the website page - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/publish,-run,-and-test-the-getting-started-template-projects.html

To publish the `Platform` project:

1. in Content Editor, on the **Publish** tab, below the **Publish** icon, click the black arrow ([image: Illustration showing the black arrow on the Publish icon.]) and click **Publish site**.
2. In the **Publish Site** window, select **Smart publish** and click **Publish**.

The RenderingHost project uses dotnet watch which automatically compiles and deploys all changes to the `myproject_rendering_1` container. You can visit the rendering host page at `https://www.myproject.localhost/`, and you can see the rendering host log by clicking the container in Docker Dashboard or by running this PowerShell command from the MyProject folder:

> docker-compose logs -f rendering

Comment: I've tried publishing but the isue still there which shows from logs is "Failed to bind pageTitle to Field`1 type.". Do you know the pageTitle value come to SitecoreController->public IActionResult Index([SitecoreRouteField] Field<string> pageTitle)?

Comment: More information, I'm using Visual Studio to publish the website, I wonder why we need to publish from The Content Editor while this is the first time I run Sitecore, I don't even know The Content Editor before.

Comment: it is Sitecore published as https://www.myproject.localhost/ and is using a web database, please try it from content editor

Comment: I have published from Content Editor but the exception still there. I don't change any things in Content Editor, only publishing.

Comment: This is video how I published, does it have any mistake? https://youtu.be/gNtHNwECsXE

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit misleading, try cm, preview the home item under myproject and you might see the correct error, it's basically related to the `license`, you might not have a license with JSS, you can verify by opening `licene.xml` in notepad and search for `Sitecore.JSS`.